# JavaScript - how to update slider position via dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, variables, slider, dynamic-programming, auto-update

I have a slider, the position or the value of the slider is saved in a variable. But now I would like it to work the other way round, so that when the value of the variable changes, the position and the value of the slider also changes, so to speak dynamically.

```
  <h2>Temperature Controll</h2>

  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input autocomplete="off" type="range" min="0" max="500" value="0" class="slider" id="temp_input">
    <p>Temp_Value: <span id="temp_output"></span></p>
  </div>

  <script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("temp_input");
    var output = document.getElementById("temp_output");

    output.innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function()
    {
      output.innerHTML = this.value;
      //tempinput = slider;
    }

    slider.addEventListener("input", function(e)
    {
    tempinput = slider.value;
    });

  </script>
```

The variable tempinput should be updated by a websocket event. If something changes in the parameter.

Would it be possible to build an EventListener for the slider in the event "receive.message" from the socket event (incoming message), to update the slider value and position?

```
    // Set_Temp1 | Slide value comes back from thread2 | set_temp1: tempinput
    if ( data_array[0] [0] === 'sensor_address' )
    {
      let tempinput = data_array[1] [1];

    }
```

Comment: _"Would it be possible to build an EventListener for the slider in the event "receive.message""_ - This would then add a new event listener when ever there's a new message.

Comment: You can set the value of the slider in the `receive.message` event handler, just like you do in the `oninput` handler of the slider.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply, can you show me this? I have try but it does not work...

Comment: `slider.value = <new value>`? _"I have try"_ - Where's that attempt? _"but it does not work"_ - What does that mean exactly?

Comment: if ( data_array[0] [0] === 'sensor_address' )
 {
      let tempinput = data_array[1] [1];
      output.innerHTML = tempinput;
 }

Comment: Ok, the value does chance but the slide position is not updating?